# What is the best method for correlation/root-cause in a time series

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, correlation

I need to find the root-cause of decline in revenue because of metric X, Y, Z.
I can find the correlation of the metrics against the revenue but I do not think, they are explaining correctly the reason of the decline.

Meaning, if the revenue is down by %10, I will need to find the the correlation coefficients of each parameter or combined to explain this based on the historical coefficient values and if the decline is beyond that, the reason of the decline would be something else to be explored as a conclusion.

What do you think the best approach for this?

Thanks.